# bootstrap: highlight clicked navbar with active class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to highlight clicked navbar with active class.

The is code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='static/images/logo.png'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav .nav-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.nav-item').addClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="navNavbar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
        
      <img style="width: 75px;" src='static/images/logo.png' class="rounded float-left"
        alt="logo">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">check</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JQuery code:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav .nav-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.nav-item').addClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Is there anything wrong for adding or removing the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar-nav .nav-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

and also please add jQuery min JS in your HTML

Comment: This worked for highlighting navbar. But because of `e.preventDefault();`, redirecting to links are not working.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani - please remove it, its not need for active class